# Question on vanishing element in finite groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. A vanishing element of $G$ is an element $g\in G$
such that $\chi (g)=0$ for some irreducible complex character $\chi $ of $G$.
Let $x$ and $y$ be two vanishing elements of $G$ such that order of $x$ is $r$
and order of $y$ is $s$, where $r$ and $s$ are primes. Assume there is not
any vanishing element of order $rs$. When $G$ has not any element of order $
rs$?

Comment: What does the question mean even? Is (r,s)=1 or r and s themselves are primes? And what does the question asks?? Is it as follows: If there is no vanishing element of order rs then we have to prove that there is no element of order rs?

Comment: @ $r$ and $s$ themselves are primes. What is the condition that the group $G$ has no element of order $rs$?